# What is “Libermilch”?

Tags: meaning, old-high-german

Grimms Kinder- und Hausmärchen 1815 #36 *Die Lange Nase* begins with the line:

> Es waren drei alte abgedankte Soldaten, die waren so alt, daß sie auch keine **Libermilch** mehr beißen konnten.

The word *Libermilch* occurs nowhere else in the first edition text.

1. What does it mean?
2. Are there any supporting documents that can be found? A dictionary entry? A line in a cookbook? An image from a manuscript?

From the context of the sentence, most people can guess what it might be (something soft), but can any documentary proof be found to definitely answer the question?

So far I found:

- There are no entries in any of the **normal dictionaries** for the word *Libermilch.*
- There is a similar word *Liebfrauenmilch,* which according to **Grimms DWb** is a very mild Rhine wine. *Libermilch* could be a shortening of *Liebfrauenmilch,* but since the text states that they *could not bite it anymore,* this does not seem likely.
- **Rheinisches Wörterbuch** has an entry for *Lubber-milch* which is described as *dicke milch* (thick milk), possibly *butter-milk.*
- **Südhessisches Wörterbuch** has an entry for *leier-milch* which is *milk skimmed through the centrifuge* or *buttermilk.*
- There are many words compounded with *milch,* but no other words that begin with an *l.*

My best guess is that *Liebermilch* is the English *buttermilk,* but I am by no means certain.

The text was removed after the first edition and placed in the Anhang, so it will not have appeared in any of the later editions of the KHM.

If possible, please provide some quotable sources, links, etc.

Comment: *Liebfrauenmilch* is very unlikely.

Comment: Es *könnte* von "Liberei", also frz. *Livree* kommen, als "was der Herr seinen Bediensteten zur Verfügung stellt" bzw. lat. "liber" im Sinne von "kostenlos"

Comment: I agree, Liebfrauenmilch is very unlikely. The Korpusbelege (Deutsches Textarchiv) only has the Grimm text as the example. The word is not found anywhere else that I see. The DTA goes back to 1488.

Comment: "Die Lange Nase" was told by Dorothea Viehmann and some of her fairy tales have french origins. So *Libermilch* may be a wrong adaption of a french word.

Comment: Back to the French - Adelungs Wörterbuch notes for Livrēe,: "Anm. Dän. Liberie, Engl. Livery, aus dem Franz. Livree, Ital. Livrea, beyde aus dem mittlern Lat. Liberata, und Liberatio, welche nicht allein die Kleidung, sondern auch die Lebensmittel, den Gehalt bedeuteten, welchen ein Herr seinen Bedienten für ihren Dienst lieferte oder gab, von liberare, liefern, weil diese Kleider von dem Herren geliefert werden." So Livrēe can refer to "food" also.

Comment: @Oliver-Grimm That's - for me - the most probable explanation as I already pointed out above. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find proof that it was ever used with "Milch"

Comment: @tofro? Yes, that is the problem - several things "look" and "sound" and "feel" like they might be the answer, but so far its the proof that is missing. If it was an easy question, I might have been able to figure it out myself. In terms of difficult words in the Grimm kHM, on a scale of 1 (easy) -10 (difficult), this is a 10.

Comment: Grimm's language is far from *old high German* (Althochdeutsch), which was already replaced by Mittelhochdeutsch in the middle ages. So this tag is not really applicable here

Comment: We should not forget that it's a children's tale, and in German. The word might not have a "standard" meaning. 
Besides, you might want to look at Low German. Some Hessian dialects are classified as low German. Kassel, home (or almost) to Dorothea Viemann, was north of the "line".

Comment: Yes. Did that. Looked at several Hessian dictionaries and I was not able to find anything. I might be up to 20 different dictionaries do far without a result. Also tried different spellings w/o success.

Comment: I reposted the question here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/libermilch.3304172/ and had a good answer from the moderator berndf (no. 9)

Answer (score 6):

Das "[Wörterbuch der niederhessischen Mundart](http://www.kasselwiki.de/index.php?title=W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_niederhessischen_Mundart,_I_%E2%80%93_L)" (also ein Mundartwörterbuch aus der Gegend, aus der das Märchen stammt) sagt folgendes zu "libern":

> **libern ● lübbern** ,coagulare, gerinnen‘, Niederhessen, allgemein üblich (Pfs. 1886); **lewwern** ,gerinnen‘, Oberellenbach (Hm. 1926). ● Vgl. mhd. liberen ,gerinnen‘. ● Siehe Lubermilch.

und zum Stichwort *Lubermilch*:

> **Lubermilch** ● ,geronnene, saure (dicke) Milch‘, hin und wieder vorkommend, z.B. auf dem Habichtswald (Vil. 1868). ● Siehe libern.

Eine weitere Schreibweise findet man im Grimm unter *libbern*:

> **libbern**, verb. gerinnen, zu einer schwammigen masse zusammenlaufen (etymologische bezüge zu lab und leber vergl. sp. 3. 460); ahd. liberôn, mhd. liberen und libberen:
>
> daʒ iʒ (das blut) ûʒ den wundin dranc
> bî stuckin, want iʒ itzunt was
> gelibbrit.
> Jeroschin 17561;
> die kürze des stammvocals ist im östlichen Norddeutschland noch vielfach gewahrt; mitteldeutsch ist liefern, s. d. vgl. auch beliebern theil 1, 1449.

Den Vokalwandel zwischen dem Verb und dem Substantiv und "u" statt "i" in der *Lubermilch* darf man hier wohl ignorieren. Ich denke, das ist eine Übereinstimmung mit der Vokabel aus dem Märchen.

Es dürfte sich also um ganz normale "[Dickmilch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickmilch)"/"Sauermilch" handeln.

Erstaunlich ist eigentlich eher, dass das Internet nur diese eine Fundstelle hergibt. Nordhessen scheint internetmäßig unterversorgt...

Die lokale Verbreitung dieses Begriffs scheint extrem auf die nordhessische Gegend um Kassel beschränkt zu sein. Es wäre interessant, wenn wir hier jemanden aus der Gegend hätten, der diesen Dialekt kennt.

Comment: Very interesting and thanks for digging this out.

Comment: @torfo. This seems the closest anyone has gotten so far! This answer "feels very right." Die Geschichte war nur in der Essten Ausgabe der KHM. Danach war die Geschichte im Anhang gedruckt. Vieleicht was das Wort so Verständlich das keine Erklärung nötig war. In anderen Texten sind Erklärungen: #1 Fretche = Frosch, 1812 #25 "Duns soviel als zog, von dinsen", 1815 #3 "1 D.h. Windchen wehe! nicht die Ausrufung ehou!" u.s.w.

Comment: I found the original dictionary that the web site mentions and that you list above. Not to be critical, but it looks like only the web page connects "libern" with "Lübber." The word "liber" is not found in the dictionary. I mention it because web info is not always 100% correct. With things like this I really like to see images of the actual printed book. As we saw before, OCR and other things lead to mistakes. Can we say with 100% certainty that "liber" is linked to "lübern" and "Liwwern"? It does say at the end: "Luther schrieb liefern = liwwern" - so we have "lieFern." But "F" is not "B"

Comment: We're getting closer.... see above edit for a trace in Grimm

Comment: Niederhessisch is a very good source and was my guess. Dorothea Viemann came from Nordhessen and the language there was not so influenced by Rhine dialects as in the rest of Hessen. The famous Low German influence line ran through northern Hessen at the time of the Grimm brothers.

Comment: Closer - yes, absolutely! Of all the things I though to do, I did not consider the spelling that doubled the b's "libbern." I considered sound shift b->v, etc. I guess that is why they say two heads are better than one. So maybe they created a new word for the KHM. I guess if you write the dictionary, you could add the word. I wonder, if they had lived, would they have added it? Jacob died while working on the entry for "FRUCHT." Wilhelm was working on entries for the letter "D" when he died several years earlier. Neither got the the letter "L"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not as well researched as to be a full answer, but here is a possible explanation:
I strongly believe the word means "thickened" or "clotted/coagulated". In Swedish we have the word "lever" which could mean liver or (blod-) *clot*. There is also a reflexive verb form derived from this wich means "to clot" or to stiffen. The word might be of a common Germanic origin.

There are old sour-milk variants that are really thick and "connected", so when you eat it you really have to bite off, else there is a all-or-nothing effect. This makes sense to the statement that the soldiors couldn't "bite off".
C.f. swedish "långfil" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lT_Ty-fJPHQ

Comment: It could. Is there any linguistic connection between "långfil", lever," "liber" and "luber"? Your answer seems close to the Rheinisches Wörterbuch entry for Lubber-milch

Comment: @Oliver-Grimm "Långfil" simply means "long" sourmilk, so there there isn't any linguistic connections. However for "lever" it seems possible, but I haven't found any sources to prove this

Comment: You are actually close. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This apparently scholarly translation renders it as "milk pudding".

http://blog.press.princeton.edu/2014/12/21/on-the-tenth-day-the-twelve-grimm-days-of-christmas/

The fact remains that Libermilch does not seem to be found in any dictionary.

PS. I reposted the question here: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/libermilch.3304172/ and had a good answer from the moderator berndf (no. 9)

Comment: I have seen that. That translation is problematic. It mixes texts from different editions. Some of the words are just nonsense. Since when was a "Hinkelbeinchen" a "gammy leg" ? It is a chicken bone, and very symbolic. It is not "an injured leg." Since when does "ein wild's Gebracht" mean "eating some venison"? "Milk pudding" just seems like the first, best, easiest thing. From the context  we can all take good guesses at what it might be - it has to be something that older men can and do/did generally eat. They will/should "bite" it. It should be soft. It could be butter, buttermilk, yogurt?

Comment: Sorry.... "eating some wild venison"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, so no guarantee, but I will try to answer your question.

The word liber seems to have three meanings that originated in the medieval age. The first is meant as a preference in favor of something else:

> Habet filium Mertin der trincket liber milch denn wyn.

This means that someone is preferring milk instead of wine. More [details here](https://books.google.at/books?id=g3OtOx2DT-QC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=liber%20milch%20wyn&source=bl&ots=XJ9IB5U2-d&sig=lQS0w66zw4WKbW6HXm5T4ppTEA4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHx9SVpPXSAhXEF5oKHefKDgQQ6AEIHjAB) and [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=J4VSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT234&lpg=PT234&dq=libermilch%20-grimm&source=bl&ots=uCWkbZaH9-&sig=FPXgIxY9FwPoyW90XACOHlISHqA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7pLa_tvbSAhUHExoKHaWUBW04ChDoAQgsMAY#v=onepage&q=libermilch%20-grimm&f=false). Today you would say: 'lieber Milch statt Wein'.

The second is somewhat the meaning comparable to over. If you are describing the origin of something in a historical sense, you would say something came from X over Y to Z. Like horses came from Central Asia over Europe to America. It's really hard to find references, but from feeling [this one](https://archive.org/stream/b21726000_0023/b21726000_0023_djvu.txt) (Encyclopaedisches Woerterbuch der medicinischen Wissenschaften) as well as [this one](https://archive.org/stream/dasschriftweseni00watt/dasschriftweseni00watt_djvu.txt) (Das Schriftwesen im Mittelalter) might fit. Just search for "liber" within those documents and read the text before and after the occurrence.

The third, and I bet the best, explanation is a medical one. It is also related to how butter is made and it is connected to the second explanation. In medieval times butter was used as medicine against infections and other illnesses. And if you have fat milk, the early stage of butter (cream) will materialize on top (over/above) the milk if you just leave the milk for some days. So butter would be the thing above the milk, where liber is the old German word for 'über' (see second explanation). For details check the medical compendium: Liber simplicium medicinarum

It explains in old German language how butter is made from the thing 'liber milch'. One could argue that the translation to 'über' is also true for the name of books, like 'liber magicae', which you could translate to 'über Magie'. But this isn't true, because in this case liber is the latin word for book.

Last but not least, butter was produced because it lasted longer than pure milk and it is rich in proteins and fat. So it was commonly used by the army for their soldiers as lasting small volume nutritious food supply.

All this fits the sentence of the fairy tale. So, Libermilch seems to be an old word for butter while 'liber' looks like a Latin word that has been imported into German language from the Mediterranean area over Tyrol (Austria) and the alps resulting in the word 'über' today.

Comment: Libermilch as an old word for butter. This makes a lot of sense! It also fits perfectly into the context of the story. The men were so old that they could not even bite butter anymore. Any way to get links? I found the book, but have not found the exact reference yet.

Comment: Bei "Liber simplicium medicinarum" und "liber magicae" dürfte es
sich eher um das lateinische "liber" (= "Buch") handeln.

Comment: Indeed. Liber is the word for book. But as I said, I'm not an expert, but the explanation above sounds feasible. I also tried to find the reference again, but since I was online on my smartphone I couldn't find it anymore. There was a old-german book about medicine and how to make butter. It said libermilch ...

Comment: "Liber magicae" means "The book of magic", not "About magic". From where do you get the idea that the Latin word "liber" was imported to German resulting in a word that means "über" (above/about)? Any reference?

Comment: Hi Uwe. You are hard one ;) Took me a while to find those references again. I added them to the posting above. The word liber occurs in sentences itself. You will see that the meaning is "über". If you google a bit longer, you will find old recipes from farmers living up in the alps (Almwirtschaft) that are talking about "liber milch" (two words). But couldn't find them right now.

Comment: I don't doubt that the word "liber" was used in the sense of "über" in the middle ages. I doubt that there is any relationship between the *German* word "liber" and the *Latin* word "liber" appearing in Latin book titles. "*Liber* + Gen." means "*Das Buch* + Gen", not "über". German "*Über* + Akk." in book titles corresponds to Latin "*De* + Abl." Your sentence *"The name of the compendium would also translate to 'über'"* is nonsense; what you wrote before is fine.

Comment: You're right. I updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: The links you are giving are very obviously either old spelling of *lieber* or scan errors from *über* (one sentence before, it's spelt "ueber". The *Liber simplicium medicinarum* I downloaded from here (http://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10198102_00001.html) you give as a source is completely in Latin - I doubt it has "Libermilch" anywhere. Please give a credible reference how *Libermilch* would relate to *Butter*. Because I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: Sorry couldn't find other references. And I spent several hours to investigate this. Won't go any further.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. Yes, I found that reference also. "Sobiech, über Milch= und Wasser=Magarine. Leipzig 1896" This is by no means an easy question! It has stumped me for a long time. It seems so easy, but I have not been able to find any references for the word. If they made up (created) the word, they must have read about it somewhere? Maybe the answer is in French somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In German you can bite whine at least in some regions and in the Reblaussong.
Beißen=to bite is part of Whine language.

Wolfgang Ambros - Die Reblaus Songtext
http://www.songtexte.com/songtext/wolfgang-ambros/die-reblaus-13dcf941.html
"drum tu den Wein ich auch nicht trinken, sondern ***beißen***,
und hab den roten grad so gern als wie den weißen."

Also Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinsprache

This does not mean that it is really whine, but it might be (with low chance.).

There is only the fairy tale entry in DWDS, a large German text corpus.

(I cannot post the link but you find it easily.)